# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I use flask in python3 to develop a website on AWS.

However when I tried to login, error occurs:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'example.cl8czkqyfcpi.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
```

How shoudl I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an inbound rule issue. If you do not setup your Inbound Rules correctly, you get connection errors. See this AWS tutorial, where this issue is discussed. This tutorial is implemented in Java, but the programming language does not matter when connection issues are concerned. You need to setup the Inbound Rules regardless of the programming language you use to develop a client app.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker